# Easing not applying to Angular trigger transitions

Tags: angular, angular-animations, angular6

I've created a 3-state sidepanel component that provides the following states:

- Collapsed - Sidepanel is completely hidden
- Thin - Icon is visible with tooltip
- Full - Icon and label are visible

The issue I have is that transitions applied via a `reveal` trigger do not perform easing as defined in their `transition` functions.

All `slide` trigger transitions are working as expected, but the `reveal` trigger just performs the style changes without any easing.

Please see below component definitions and [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/transition-easing-issues?file=app%2Fcomponents%2Fsidepanel%2Fpanel-link.component.ts):

***SidepanelComponent Template***

```html
<mat-nav-list [@slide]="state">
  <panel-link link="/home" [state]="state" label="Home" icon="home"></panel-link>
</mat-nav-list>
```

***SidepanelComponent Definition***

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';
import { SidepanelService } from '../../services/sidepanel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidepanel',
  templateUrl: 'sidepanel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidepanel.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'slide', [
        state('collapse', style({
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0
        })),
        state('thin', style({
          width: '*',
          opacity: 1
        })),
        state('full', style({
          width: '*',
          opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('collapse => thin', animate('500ms ease-out')),
        transition('thin => full', animate('500ms ease-out')),
        transition('full => collapse', animate('500ms ease-in'))
      ]
    )
  ]
})
export class SidepanelComponent {
  private state: string;
  constructor(
    public sidepanel: SidepanelService
  ) {
    sidepanel.state$.subscribe((s: string) => this.state = s);
  }
}
```

***PanelLinkComponent Template***

```html
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="link"
                 routerLinkActive="active"
                 [@slide]="state"
                 [matTooltip]="label"
                 [matTooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition"
                 [matTooltipDisabled]="state !== 'thin'">
  <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  <span [@reveal]="state">{{label}}</span>
</a>
```

***PanelLinkComponent Definition***

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'panel-link',
  templateUrl: 'panel-link.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger(
      'slide', [
        state('collapse', style({
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0,
        })),
        state('thin', style({
          width: '*',
          opacity: 1
        })),
        state('full', style({
          width: '*',
          opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('collapse => thin', animate('500ms ease-out')),
        transition('full => collapse', animate('500ms ease-in'))
      ]
    ),
    trigger(
      'reveal', [
        state('collapse', style({
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0,
          'margin-left': 0,
          'margin-right': 0,
        })),
        state('thin', style({
          width: 0,
          opacity: 0,
          'margin-left': 0,
          'margin-right': 0,
        })),
        state('full', style({
          width: '100%',
          opacity: 1,
          'margin-left': '15px',
          'margin-right': '10px',
        })),
        transition('thin => full', animate('500ms ease-out')),
        transition('full => collapse', animate('500ms ease-in'))
      ]
    )
  ]
})
export class PanelLinkComponent {
  @Input() link: string;
  @Input() state = 'thin';
  @Input() label = 'Home';
  @Input() tooltipPosition = 'right';
  @Input() icon = 'home';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I ended up removing the `reveal` trigger and used CSS transitions based on an open / closed state to accomplish what I was trying to do.

***PanelLinkComponent Style***

```css
a span.closed {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  transition: opacity 100ms, width 100ms, margin-left 100ms, margin-right 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

a span.open {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: opacity 100ms, width 100ms, margin-left 100ms, margin-right 100ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

***PanelLinkComponent Template***

```html
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="link"
                 routerLinkActive="active"
                 [@slide]="state"
                 [matTooltip]="label"
                 [matTooltipPosition]="tooltipPosition"
                 [matTooltipDisabled]="state !== 'thin'">
  <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  <span [ngClass]="{'closed': state !== 'full', 'open': state === 'full'}">{{label}}</span>
</a>
```